# Could someone look at some jQuery I'm having an issue with?(setInterval, fadeIn/fadeOut)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, setinterval, fade

I need to have three elements that alternate with a fade transition. I have it working for the most part, but for some reason when it returns to the first element it skips the fade and just appears. I'm sure there is something fairly obvious I'm missing here, but I just don't see it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/hcarleton/qLNyt/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id='one' class='selection'>
        <h3>ONE</h3>
    </div>
    <div id='two' class='selection'>
        <h3>TWO</h3>
    </div>
    <div id='three' class='selection'>
        <h3>THREE</h3>
    </div>
    <div id='console'>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```css
div {
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:10;
}
#one {
    background-color:#aabbcc;
}
#two {
    background-color:#bbccaa;
}
#three {
    background-color:#ccaabb;
}
#console {
    width:500px;
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:25px;
    background-color:#dddddd;
}
.top {
    z-index:20;
}
p {
    margin:5px;
}
```

javascript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fade = 1000;
    var wait = 1000;
    var $selection = $('.selection');
    var selectionQty = $selection.length;
    var c = 0;
    $('.selection').fadeOut(0);
    $('.selection').first().fadeIn(0);
    setInterval(
        function() {
            c+=1;
            if(c == selectionQty) {
                c = 0;
            }
            $selection.eq(c).addClass('top').fadeIn(fade);
            $selection.delay(fade).fadeOut(0).removeClass('top');
            $selection.eq(c).fadeIn(0);
        },
        fade+wait
    );

    $('#console').append('<p>-'+selectionQty+'</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `setInterval()` and maintain a synchronous chain of events. Use `setTimeout()` within the callback functions of your animations.

You have three animations triggering simultaneously.

```
$selection.eq(c).addClass('top').fadeIn(fade);
$selection.delay(fade).fadeOut(0).removeClass('top');
$selection.eq(c).fadeIn(0);
```

Which one finishes first/last? Generally, you'll want to use `setTimeout()` when the last one finishes (there are exceptions).

Comment: Thanks, using setTimeout on the second and third animation within the setInterval worked perfectly.